# Configure gradle to download sources and javadocs by default

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

There are a lot of questions and answers how to modify gradle projects to download sources of dependencies but is there a way to set it globally for my user and not in every project (with IntelliJ)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a custom Gradle project template and use it for creating new projects:

- Create a new empty Gradle project through IntelliJ IDEA wizard
- Add `idea` plugin and its configuration to `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
}
```

```
idea {
    module {
        downloadJavadoc = true
        downloadSources = true
    }
}
```

See https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.html for more information about the `idea` plugin

- `File | New Project Setup | Save Project as Template...`
- Use this template for creating Gradle projects

Comment: I want these settings apply to unmodified projects checked out from third party repos